# Learning to code, I have a question about IF on python

Tags: python

So I'm learning to code on Python and have some questions about how the IF statement works here since it seems to be ignoring my elif's.

The only result I get is the last one so I tried putting other options and erasing that last one and the result is I just get no answer at all.

```
print('name:')
name=input()
if name=='John':
  print('Sup John')
elif name!='John':
  print('Sup stanger')

print('age?')
age=input()
if (age.isdigit())==26:
  print('Yup')
elif (age.isdigit())<=0:
  print('WUT?!')
elif (age.isdigit())>=100:
  print('Are you inmortal?')
elif (age.isdigit())<=25: #Only result I get no matter what
  print('Too young')
```

Comment: `isdigit()` is a _logical test_ that returns true/false so it can never be equal to 26

Comment: did you check `print( age.isdigit() )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ignoring your elifs. You have just misunderstood what `isdigit` is.

`isdigit` tells you whether all the characters in a string are digits or not. It does not convert a string to a digit; it returns True or False.

To convert to an integer, use `int`.

```
if int(age) == 26:
   ...
```

Comment: Yup, sorry I´m very new to python and coding but this totally solved it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned you're trying to learn Python, I'll be a little explicit with my answer. 
`isdigit` checks if a string is numeric or not. Let's take an example.

```
>>> s = "23"
>>> k = "abc"
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(k)
<class 'str'>
>>> s.isdigit()
True
>>> k.isdigit()
False
```

In your case, the first `if` checks the string and gets a True and the code exists the conditional. So your code should look something like this.

```
print('name:')
name = input()
if name=='John':
  print('Sup John')
else:
  print('Sup stanger')

print('age?')
age = input()
if int(age) == 26:
  print('Yup')
elif int(age) <= 0:
  print('WUT?!')
elif int(age) >= 100:
  print('Are you inmortal?')
elif int(age) <= 25: #Only result I get no matter what
  print('Too young')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, totally missed how isdigit worked, thanks a lot!